# How can I run a VS Code task based on the current selected C/C++ configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to run a VS Code task based on the currently selected C/C++ configuration (defined in my `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file) by using the `when` task property in `tasks.json`. How can I retrieve the name of the current C/C++ configuration?

A bit more detail for context: I have two configurations: "UHK 60 v1" and "UHK 60 v2. I want to run task A or task B according to the current configuration. The tasks `cd` into the configuration-specific build directory and execute `make`.

Comment: with [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) commands `pickStringRemember` and `remember` you can pass info from chosen launch config to tasks

Comment: @rioV8 I don't see how I can retrieve the current configuration (contained in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json`) with the mentioned commands.

Comment: use other commands, the current C/C++ config should be saved as a setting, get that with `extension.commandvariable.config.expression` then use `extension.commandvariable.file.content` to read the json file and extract the info you want with an expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_supported-variables, which state:

> You can allow `tasks.json` or `launch.json` to query the current active configuration from `c_cpp_properties.json`. To do this, use the variable `${command:cpptools.activeConfigName}` as an argument in a `tasks.json` or `launch.json` script.